# L'Hopital's Rule $\infty - \infty$ in numerator of rational function

Tags: calculus, limits

I am currently taking a course on Calculus 1. We just recently went over L'Hopital's Rule, which states the following:

When evaluating $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, if direct substitution yields 0/0 or $\pm\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, then the limit of our original expression is equal to $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$.

However, I recently came across the following problem:

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{5x - 2x^2}{e^x+3}$

While the solution key indicates that we may simply use L'Hopital's Rule, I do not understand why. Moreover, if we utilize direct substitution, we will be left with $\frac{\infty - \infty}{\infty}$. Presently, this is not equivalent to the indeterminate form $\pm\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Is there some sort of manipulation we can do to show that $\frac{\infty - \infty}{\infty}$ is equivalent to $\pm\frac{\infty}{\infty}$?

Comment: For  $x>\frac52$, you should be able to see $5x-2x^2 < -x^2$ is negative and $\to -\infty$

Comment: Two things to observe: first $5x-2x^2\to-\infty $ as $x\to\infty$ and second, L'Hospital's Rule works on the form $\text{anything} /\infty$ so that we don't care what happens with the numerator.

Comment: Divide the numerator and denominator by $x$, which you can do for $x \gt 0$.  Just note that $\frac {e^x}{x} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and then you're set up to use L'Hopital.

Comment: For this particular problem, you could split it into $\frac{5x}{e^x+3} - \frac{2x^2}{e^x+3}$ and solve the limit of each term separately. But this approach doesn't always work as it could yield $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh this isnt true. L’Hopital’s works for an indeterminate form not anything/$\inf$

Comment: @TeodorasPaura: you should check the proof of the rule in [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) which deals with case 2. The case 2 requires that $|g(x) |\to\infty$ when trying to evaluate limit of $f(x) /g(x) $. One doesn't need to know the limit of  numerator $f(x)$ here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh wow thank you! Learnt something new, was not aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why we use L'Hôptial's rule in this case: It's because you've already shown that through direct substitution, you get an indeterminate value of the form $\frac\infty\infty$ (in this case, you should realize that $\frac{5x-2x^2}{e^x+3}$ can, in fact, be rewritten as $\frac{5x}{e^x+3}-\frac{2x^2}{e^x+3}$, which direct substitution then gives us $\frac\infty\infty-\frac\infty\infty$, which you were looking for.)

Now, if you want to figure out the limit using L'Hôpital's rule, if you've gone over deriviates already (which you most likely have, seeing you have recently going over limits), you'll know that $\frac d{dx}e^x=e^x$. So, what do we do to solve the limit? We split your one limit into 2 limits (to more easily show what I am doing for simplicity) to get$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{5x-2x^2}{e^x+3}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{5x}{e^x+3}-\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{2x^2}{e^x+3}$$and now we apply L'Hôpital's rule once on the first limit and twice on the second limit to get$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{5}{e^x}-\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{4}{e^x}$$And then direct substitution gives us$$\dfrac5{\infty}-\dfrac4\infty=0-0=0$$So L'Hôpital's rule does work here (luckily) since it always works for limits of the form$$\dfrac00\text{ and }\dfrac\infty\infty$$

Comment: Do not need to separate the expression as two terms of $\frac{5x}{e^x+3}$ and $(-\frac{2x^2}{e^x+3})$. Simply apply L'Hôpital's rule to the whole expression. That is, $\frac{d}{dx}(numerator)=5-4x$, and doing it again yields $(-4)$, while doing this twice on the denominator yields $e^x$. Then the ratio is $0$ when $x$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @user295357 I'm aware of that. The only reason I did that was to more easily show my work for OP for simplicity

Comment: In general, separating into two terms for such problem is not a good thing to do. It often leads to wrong results.

Comment: We can also write $\frac{x^2}{e^x}\frac{5/x-2}{1+3e^{-x}}$. The limit of the second fraction is $-2$ by inspection. Then use L'Hopital for the first fraction.

Comment: @user295357 Why could separating the fraction often lead to wrong results with these types of problems? Is it because I applied L'Hôpital's rule a different number of times on the 2 separate fractions?

Comment: @CrSb0001  Sorry for I do not have an example by hand right now but there are such cases. In short, the key factor determines the limit of such problem is the **relative changing rate of the numerator to the changing rate of the denominator**, or, just **to compare who changes fast than another** when $x$ goes to infinity (or a value). If the numerator is separated into two (or more) terms, the (sum of the relative changing rate of each term) **might be or might not be** equal to the relative changing rate of the numerator. Anyway, I respect your thinking if you have different opinion.

Comment: @user295357 Oh okay, no that makes more sense now, thank you for explaining, was just having trouble understanding tbh.

Answer (score 3):

As $x$ becomes very large, $|-2x^2|$ is much larger than $|5x|$. So  the top is "equal" to $-\infty$, because the $5x$ term is negligible in size compared to the $-2x^2$ term. (For example, if we plug in $x = 1000$, we get $-2\cdot(1000)^2 + 5\cdot100 = -2000000 + 5000$.)

In general, any non-constant polynomial will be plus or minus infinity for the purposes of L'Hopital's Rule. (Positive infinity if the largest power term has a positive coefficient, minus if the largest power term has a negative coefficient.) And as other commenters mention, you don't actually need the top to be infinity to apply L'Hopital's rule; it works either way.

It's worth being very careful when you substitute infinity into these expressions directly. Infinity isn't a real number that you can add and subtract; the direct substitution method is a shorthand for finding the limit of the top and the bottom. If you're confused, try to find the limit directly.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative perspective.

Before you can apply L'Hopital's rule to the original problem, you need to show that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 5x - 2x^2 = -\infty.$$

This is easily done by re-writing $~f(x) = x \times (5 - 2x).~$

Let $~M~$ be any negative real number, no matter how small.  Choose $~x_0 \in \Bbb{R^+},~$ such that
$~x_0 = \max\left[ ~|M| + 1, 3 ~\right].$

Now, consider any $~x \geq x_0.~$

Then, $~5 - 2x \leq -1,~$ and $~x > |M| \implies f(x) < -|M| = M.~$

Thus, $~\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = -\infty.$